# Putting random latitude and longitude in google maps geolocation?

Tags: geolocation

I have latitude and longitude of some cities and I want to input it the geocoder randomly. Can anyone please tell me how do I do that. The values are both negative and float. for an instance mexico lat/long 23.634501,-102.552784

myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.352083,103.819836);

I want to put values randomly from a set of values in Latlng function. Thanks

Comment: Using what programming language?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify your programming language, so I'll answer language agnostic.

I'll assume you have a Point type that can take two double values, e.g.

```
class Point
{
    double Latitude;
    double Longitude;
}
```

and that you have a list or set of instances of Point representing the set of latitude/longitude pairs you want to select from.

```
List<Point> points;
```

Just generate a random integer between 0 and (set size -1).  Use that random integer as an index into the list.

```
int index = Random(0, points.Length-1);
Point myRandomPoint = points[index];
```

Now use that Point in your call to Google

```
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myRandomPoint.Latitude, myRandomPoint.Longitude);
```